# What about launching doLayout() in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

What do you think about something like this :

```
public class HeavyJTable extends JTable implements Runnable {
public HeavyJTable (AbstractTableModel m) {
    super(m);
    /* .... */
    this.setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    this.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    final TableColumnModel columnModel = this.getColumnModel();
    int width = 60;
    for (int column = 0; column < this.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = this.getCellRenderer(0, column);
        Component comp = this.prepareRenderer(renderer, 0, column);
       if(comp == null)
            continue;
        width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
    super.doLayout();
}

@Override
public void doLayout() {
    if (getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth() == getWidth()) { 
        return; //filter some useless refreshes
    } else
        new Thread(this).start();
}
```

}

The context : I have several `JTable` in a differents tabs of a `JTabbedPane` that listen updates/inserts/deletes and updates their own data alone. All those table are resizeable from a spinner. So it's a lot of data and a lot of refreshes.

So I wanted to put all the painting process in another thread (each sensible part is protected by semaphores).

What do you think about this ? Is there any other better options ? I'm thinking about `SwingWorkers`. Or running sets of `doLayout()` in different pools of thread.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm asking what do you propose. I have a basic computer and even without rendering my main thread is busy, the program need others services and resources too. So I don't think that's it's that premature to dedicate a thread for the view of tables in that context.

Comment: Worry about design/managability. If you are worried about memory/performance, profile your app to see if there is anything to worry about

Comment: Thanks Vince, I'll check the profiling. But I already spent a lot of time on optimization of logic. I'm pretty sure that it comes from the view now when I look at the stack.

Is there a way to skip X `doLayout()` per `JTable` ?

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe - *"So I wanted to put all the painting process in another thread"* - Can't be done, that's not how painting works.  Focus on loading the data outside of the EDT (using `SwingWorker`s) and updating the UI from within the EDT

Answer (score 2):

Swing is NOT thread safe, you should never do anything (directly or indirectly) which will update or change the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

> So I wanted to put all the painting process in another thread (each sensible part is protected by semaphores).

No, this is not how painting works.  Painting is ALWAYS done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread (painting events are en-queued onto the `EventQueue`).  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

> The context : I have several JTable in a differents tabs of a JTabbedPane that listen updates/inserts/deletes and updates their own data alone. All those table are resizeable from a spinner. So it's a lot of data and a lot of refreshes.

Separate the management of your data from your view.  Use background threads to load the data off the EDT and then resync the results back when they are completed

> What do you think about this ? Is there any other better options ? I'm thinking about SwingWorkers. Or running sets of doLayout() in different pools of thread.

`SwingWorker` would be a far better solution, but you would use it to load the data (in the `doInBackground` method) and update the UI either through the `process`/`publish` functionality or `done` method depending on your needs